# Identifying duplicate within groups by latest date

Tags: r

I currently have a data frame that looks like this:

```
   ID Value       Date
1   1     A   1/1/2018
2   1     B   2/3/1988
3   1     B   6/3/1994
4   2     A  12/6/1999
5   2     B 24/12/1957
6   3     A   9/8/1968
7   3     B  20/9/2016
8   3     C  15/4/1993
9   3     C   9/8/1994
10  4     A   8/8/1988
11  4     C   6/4/2001
```

Within each `ID` I would like to identify a row where there is a duplicate `Value`. The `Value` that I would like to identify is the duplicate with the most recent `Date`.

The resulting data frame should look like this:

```
   ID Value       Date mostRecentDuplicate
1   1     A   1/1/2018                  0
2   1     B   2/3/1988                  0
3   1     B   6/3/1994                  1
4   2     A  12/6/1999                  0
5   2     B 24/12/1957                  0
6   3     A   9/8/1968                  0
7   3     B  20/9/2016                  0
8   3     C  15/4/1993                  0
9   3     C   9/8/1994                  1
10  4     A   8/8/1988                  0
11  4     C   6/4/2001                  0`
```

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `dplyr` we can first convert `Date` to actual date value, then `group_by` `ID` and `Value` and assign value 1 in the group where there is more than 1 row and the `row_number` is same as row number of maximum `Date`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, "%d/%m/%Y")) %>%
  group_by(ID, Value) %>%
  mutate(mostRecentDuplicate = +(n() > 1 & row_number() == which.max(Date))) %>%
  ungroup()


# A tibble: 11 x 4
#      ID Value Date       mostRecentDuplicate
#   <int> <fct> <date>                   <int>
# 1     1 A     2018-01-01                   0
# 2     1 B     1988-03-02                   0
# 3     1 B     1994-03-06                   1
# 4     2 A     1999-06-12                   0
# 5     2 B     1957-12-24                   0
# 6     3 A     1968-08-09                   0
# 7     3 B     2016-09-20                   0
# 8     3 C     1993-04-15                   0
# 9     3 C     1994-08-09                   1
#10     4 A     1988-08-08                   0
#11     4 C     2001-04-06                   0
```